# Are there any library in .Net to do some basic audio editing?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

What I need to do is insert silences in an audio, insert other audios, mix other audios (insert them with an overlapping section) and so on.

Are there any libraries for .Net (I'm using C#) that could do such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio)

NAudio Features:

- Play back audio using a variety of APIs

  - WaveOut
  - DirectSound
  - ASIO (not currently working with all soundcards)
  - WASAPI (Windows Vista Core Audio)
- Decompress audio from different Wave Formats using ACM codecs
- Record audio using WaveIn or WASAPI
- Read and Write standard .WAV files
- Mix and manipulate audio streams using a 32 bit mixing engine
- Support for reading from a variety of audio file-formats including:

  - MP3
  - SoundFont
  - MIDI
  - SFZ
- Extensive support for reading and writing MIDI files
- Full MIDI event model
- Basic support for Windows Mixer APIs
- A collection of Windows Forms Controls useful for .NET
  Some basic audio effects, including a compressor

Comment: It seems NAudio is 32bit only. Am I wrong?

Comment: seems to be 32-bit only: http://naudio.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46000

Answer (score 2):

I've used Alvas Audio (http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) and I've been pretty happy with it.  Their support team is fairly helpful as well.